# RxJava get cache then wait for network calls to update

Tags: android, caching, rx-java

Can we have any workaround for this problem.
I'm trying to get cache to show to user first then call network api to update current data (if device have network connection)
How we can combine them together ?

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are trying to work around? Are you able to show the cached content to the user? Are you able to update the cache and show the updated content to the user? Are you having trouble getting through any of those steps?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use your cache and api as observables whose emits same class of items, you are probably looking for [merge](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) method.